# How do i access attribute [field] from subclass and create it in constructor of a subclass?

Tags: java

> I have this piece of code:

```
 public class Zabojnik {
            private String oznaka;
            private int maksimalnaTeza;
            private int maksimalnoSteviloPredmetov;
            **private Object  predmeti[];**
            }.....
```

> I would like to create **Object predmeti[]** in in construcor of my subclass:

```
public class HladilniZabojnik extends Zabojnik {

    public HladilniZabojnik() {
    }

    public HladilniZabojnik(String oznaka, int maksimalnoSteviloPredmetov, int maksimalnaTeza) {
        super(oznaka, maksimalnoSteviloPredmetov, maksimalnaTeza);

    }

}
```

> How do i do this without changing predmeti[] to protected ???

Comment: If predmeti has a setter method, use it, otherwise you're in a bit of trouble

Comment: will try ty for your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have a setter for that field:

```
public HladilniZabojnik(String oznaka, int maksimalnoSteviloPredmetov, int maksimalnaTeza) {
    super(oznaka, maksimalnoSteviloPredmetov, maksimalnaTeza);
    setPredmeti(new Object[size]); // use the size you need/want
}
```

If don't have a setter, but you do have access to the parent class, you can change or add another constructor:

```
class Zabojnik {
    // fields
    // optional constructor of 3 fields
    public Zabojnik(String oznaka, int maksimalnoSteviloPredmetov, int maksimalnaTeza, Object[] predmeti) {
        // ... rest of the constructor or call to this() with the 3 fields
        this.predmeti = predmeti;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man I fixed my problem, it was kinda a dumb of me that I didn't put Object[] predmeti in construcor input.
TY again!!!

Comment: @žankovač Accept the answer then.